# Always getting an empty white window when starting nw.exe

Tags: javascript, windows, nw.js

I have problem with NW.js, when I run nw.exe or my project directly in cmd "nw.exe ./path/of/myApp", NW.js doesn’t work. I always get an empty white window. See this animation:

[image]

Note: my cursor always loads by interval when the NW.js window is active. I’ve waited 5 minutes but the program was not loaded.

But 10 minuts before, NW.js worked correctly. Now, after reboot, the problem persist.

I use NW.JS SDK 64bits (lasted version online).

I have tried with NW.js Stable (not sdk) but I have same problem.

Comment: Activate window toolbar for access to devtools, and see does the console log anything. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/debugging-with-devtools

Comment: when i active window toolbar, the window has already blank... I cant have access to the toolbar...

Comment: There is no simple answer here. You will have try to debug it and find the source of the issue. Try to open devtools programmatically as the first thing in your app. Delete NW temp files. Probably it's something inside your app...like not working properly require(), too long node_modules dependency path etc. Delete parts of your app and narrow down the problem.